# SQL Server: finding if a client exists (and the account they own) in MULTIPLE columns of the accounts table

Tags: sql-server, subquery, exists

I'm trying to find the list of customers that own (or co-own) an account and the account number.

Our CLIENT table contains our client data, identified with a `clientId` (table also contains demographics and contact details).

Our ACCOUNTS table contains account information where a `clientId` can exist in 1 or 5 columns (one account can have up to 5 co-owners).

My code looks like this, but is agonizingly slow. Is this the correct approach? Are there other approaches that are less expensive?

```
SELECT
    c.*, aa.accountNo 
FROM
    client AS c, accounts AS aa
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM accounts AS a
            WHERE CAST(a.Account_Date AS Date) >= '2010-11-15' 
              AND CAST(a.Account_Date AS Date) <= '2017-04-24'
              AND c.clientId IN (a.Owner1, a.Owner2, a.Owner3, a.Owner4, a.Owner5))
```

Comment: How long is agonisingly slow and what performance results are you looking for? How does it perform to other similar queries (to rule out network bandwidth issues)? How is the query being executed - directly from a SQL script or encapsulated within a program? What is the data size of each table - 10k, 100k, 1mill rows? Do you have any indexes on the underlying tables? All of these things would help with a recommendation, but without those I would explore turning this query into an indexed view to see if that helps performance.

Comment: `client as c, accounts as aa` <-- don't do this. This syntax was replaced with the much more explicit and less error-prone `INNER JOIN` 30 years ago or so now. Also please specify what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: "How long ....?" selecting top10 takes around 30 secs, Size ACCOUNTS ~480,000 and CLIENTS = 2,600,000,; run from script in the SSMS; indexes are unknown (these are exploratory tables, not strictly well architected. I will explore indexed view thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have explodes the data set and scans accounts twice. Also we shouldn't have to *cast* the column side to fit into a date range, there's now way that's beneficial (it might not always cause a scan [but it's still not great](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186)). Try:

```
SELECT c.*, a.accountNo
FROM dbo.accounts AS a
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES(Owner1),(Owner2),(Owner3),(Owner4),(Owner5)
) AS ac(clientId)
INNER JOIN dbo.client AS c
ON c.clientId = ac.clientId
WHERE a.Account_Date >= '20101115'
  AND a.Account_Date <  '20170425';
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=597008a8737c3abe4703b35fc6fdf7e9)

Answer (score 1):

**Your primary issue is lack of normalization.** You should not have five `Owner` columns. Instead you should have a separate table of `AccountOwner`. Then you can simply join it.

> This is effectively what you get from @AaronBetrand's answer, except that that one cannot be indexed as it is virtual.

Note also:

- There was no need to access `accounts` again in the subquery.
- Always use explicit join syntax, not the implicit `,` syntax.
- Never cast a column in order to filter or join it. Always cast the constants instead. In this case you don't even need to cast them.

```sql
SELECT
  c.*,
  a.accountNo
FROM Client AS c
JOIN AccountOwner AS ao ON ao.OwnerId = c.ClientId
JOIN Accounts AS a
    ON a.AccountNo = ao.AccountNo
   AND a.Account_Date >= '20101115'
   AND a.Account_Date <  '20170425';
```

For this query to work efficiently, you will need the following indexes

```
Account (Account_Date, AccountNo)
AccountOwner (AccountNo, OwnerId)
Client (ClientId) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)
```

An alternative set of indexes may prove a better access strategy (you need to test)

```
Account (AccountNo) INCLUDE (Account_Date)
AccountOwner (OwnerId, AccountNo)
Client (ClientId) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)
```

Comment: Thank. I'm but a new data analyst in the discovery phase of a project. These are exploratory tables I'm dealing with and I don't have CREATE VIEW permissions yet

Comment: Then you've just discovered one of the many pitfalls of bad normalization. I suggest you pass this through to your superiors/DBA team/whoever designed this